# regex to allow ampersands in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What do I need to do to alter this to allow ampersands in the $result?

```
function replace($s){
    $result = preg_replace("/[^\p{Latin}0-9'-]+/u", "", html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES));
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `&` to the exclusion in the pattern.

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^\p{Latin}0-9&'-]+/u", "", html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES));
```

(Be careful: the `-` should stay at the end, otherwise it might be interpreted as describing a range of characters, like `0-9`)